# Simultaneous predictions

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have fitted a linear model using `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`

Lets call it `model`

I have a list of `X_1, X_2, ..., X_n`

And what I do is predict them each one by one like:

```py
for X_i in list:
    model.predict(X_i)
```

Is there a faster way to do this? Maybe I can concatenate all X_i together and then predict them all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `predict` with a `numpy.array` and get back a `numpy.array` of predictions:

Take a look at this MVCE, using fit to odd numbers of `X` for *y = 2X* to predict even numbers of `X`:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

X = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
y = [2, 6, 10, 14, 18]
lr = LinearRegression()
X = np.array(X)
# However, you need to reshape your X array to be 2-D instead of 1-D.
X = X[:, None]

lr.fit(X, y)

X_pred = [2, 4, 6, 8]
# Combine numpy array and reshape into one statement
X_pred = np.array(X_pred)[:, None] 

y_pred = lr.predict(X_pred)
y_pred
```

Output:

```
array([4.,  8., 12., 16.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `X1 ... XN` are `numpy` arrays you can [concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) them like this:

```
X = np.concatenate((X1, X2, X3), axis=0)
```

And pass this array to `fit`/`predict`.